# How to customize AWS ALB name using kubernetes_ingress_v1 terraform resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, aws-application-load-balancer

Can we customize name of AWS ALB created by using terraform kubernetes_ingress_v1 resource?
Currently without adding any name annotation, it is creating AWS ALB with name like:

```
k8s-namesp-env-10976a981e
```

I tried adding annotation in the kubernetes_ingress_v1 metadata section:

```
"alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name"      = "my-custom-alb-name"
```

but this didn't updated the AWS ALB name however it updated the K8s ingress.

This is my kubernetes_ingress_v1:

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "module_alb" {
  wait_for_load_balancer = true
  metadata {
    name      = "${var.prefix}-${var.environment}-module-alb"
    namespace = var.environment
    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class"                       = "alb"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name"      = "my-custom-alb-name"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme"                  = "internet-facing"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type"             = "instance"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-group-attributes" = "stickiness.enabled=true,stickiness.lb_cookie.duration_seconds=14400"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn"         = data.aws_acm_certificate.ssl_certificate.arn
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-policy"              = "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags"                    = "Name=${var.environment}-eventgateway-alb,Namespace=${var.environment},Cluster=${var.prefix}_eks_cluster,tl:prefix=${var.prefix},tl:dnp:environment=${var.prefix}-${var.environment},tl:stack=${var.prefix}-${var.environment}-module-tf"
      # Access logs to s3
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes" = "access_logs.s3.enabled=true,access_logs.s3.bucket=abc-prods-${var.region},access_logs.s3.prefix=ALB"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes"            = "201,404"
    }
  }
  spec {
    rule {
      host = "*.abc.com"
      http {
        path {
          path = "/*"
          backend {
            service {
              name = kubernetes_service.alb[count.index].metadata.0.name
              port {
                number = 443
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```